# Android bluetooth printer app works fine in debug mode but doesn't work in release mode

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am writing an Android app to print text on a bluetooth thermal printer.
[Here is the complete code](https://github.com/rishadali/bluetooth-thermal-printer)

The app works fine in the debug mode but when I generate a signed APK and install it on the device, it does not respond at all.

I have tried different solution suggested on stackoverflow but non of them worked.

This is my main activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.lvrenyang.io.IOCallBack;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler mHandler; // Our main handler that will receive callback notifications
    // #defines for identifying shared types between calling functions
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1; // used to identify adding bluetooth names

    private static String TAG = "MAIN_ACTIVITY";
    private Activity activity;
    private Button btnConnect;

    private String name = "MTP-II";
    private String mac_address = "02:15:44:31:49:05";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Get the activity
        this.activity = this;

        //Button from the XML view
        btnConnect = findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);

        //Start the Init Work Service Async task
        new InitWorkService().execute();

        //Set onClickListener for test print button
        btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    //Check if name and address are set
                    if (name != "null" && mac_address != "null" && mac_address.contains(":")) {

                        if (!WorkService.workThread.isConnected()) {
                            WorkService.workThread.connectBt(mac_address);
                            //Sleep for 3 seconds
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(3000);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }
                        }
                        //Check if connected
                        if (WorkService.workThread.isConnected()) {
                            //Collect data in background Thread
                            new PrintData().execute();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, Global.toast_notconnect, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Please setup printer first!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e.fillInStackTrace());}
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Background Async Task
     * */
    private class InitWorkService extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... args){
            try{
                WorkService.cb = new IOCallBack() {
                    public void OnOpen() {
                        if (null != mHandler) {
                            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Global.MSG_IO_ONOPEN);
                            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                        }
                    }
                    public void OnClose() {
                        if (null != mHandler) {
                            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Global.MSG_IO_ONCLOSE);
                            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e.fillInStackTrace());
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
            try {
                mHandler = new MHandler(MainActivity.this);
                WorkService.addHandler(mHandler);

                if (null == WorkService.workThread) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, WorkService.class);
                    startService(intent);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e.fillInStackTrace());
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Unable to initiate the WorkService!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task
     * */
    class PrintData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... args){
            try{
                int nTextAlign=1;
                String text = "Test message!\r\n\r\n\r\n";
                String encoding = "UTF-8";
                byte[] hdrBytes = {0x1c, 0x26, 0x1b, 0x39, 0x01};

                Bundle dataAlign = new Bundle();
                Bundle dataTextOut = new Bundle();
                Bundle dataHdr = new Bundle();

                dataHdr.putByteArray(Global.BYTESPARA1, hdrBytes);
                dataHdr.putInt(Global.INTPARA1, 0);
                dataHdr.putInt(Global.INTPARA2, hdrBytes.length);

                dataAlign.putInt(Global.INTPARA1, nTextAlign);

                dataTextOut.putString(Global.STRPARA1, text);
                dataTextOut.putString(Global.STRPARA2, encoding);

                WorkService.workThread.handleCmd(Global.CMD_POS_WRITE,dataHdr);
                WorkService.workThread.handleCmd(Global.CMD_POS_SALIGN,dataAlign);
                WorkService.workThread.handleCmd(Global.CMD_POS_STEXTOUT,dataTextOut);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e.fillInStackTrace());
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){}
    }


    @Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint()
    {
        Log.d("onUserLeaveHint","Home button pressed");
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
        //Unregister bluetooth receiver
        try{unregisterReceiver(bluetoothReceiver);}catch(Exception e){}
        //Disconnect bt connection
        try{WorkService.workThread.disconnectBt();}catch(Exception e){}
        // remove the handler
        try{WorkService.delHandler(mHandler);}catch(Exception e){}
        mHandler = null;
    }

    /**
     * Broadcast receiver for bluetooth state changes
     */
    private final BroadcastReceiver bluetoothReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED))
            {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
                switch (state)
                {
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
//                        closeConnection();//Close on going connection and disable button
                        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private static class MHandler extends Handler {
        WeakReference<MainActivity> mActivity;
        MHandler(MainActivity activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            MainActivity theActivity = mActivity.get();
            switch (msg.what) {

                case Global.CMD_POS_STEXTOUTRESULT:
                case Global.CMD_POS_WRITERESULT: {
                    int result = msg.arg1;
                    Toast.makeText(
                            theActivity,
                            (result == 1) ? Global.toast_success
                                    : Global.toast_fail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.v(TAG, "Result: " + result);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Is any exception occured.If yes measn post that log cat information.It will helpfull for finding the reason for failure

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned it is working fine in the debug mode or when I run directly from the Android Studio without any exception but when I generate the signed APK, it does't respond. I dont see any exceptions in the Logcat. Can you try to download the project and generate release apk yourself, please, to see if you can spot something?? Thank you

Comment: Hi ,Ali in that file android  manifest (https://github.com/rishadali/bluetooth-thermal-printer/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) the course loacation permission not there .Add that permission and check it

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J thanks I have tried that as well but still not working. Should it not throw exception or warning in case of permission issue while debugging?

Comment: I think some exception occured and control comes to catch block of the doinbackground method of the InitWorkService or PrintData .Add the appropriate log information then it is reducing the complexity of finding root cause.Post the log here

Comment: Hey Quick question, when you generate the signed apk, are you running it on the emulator or on a physical device? if so what device are you running the signed apk on? cheers

Comment: Please publish the build.gradle(Module:app) code

Comment: Furthermore, when you install & run the signed apk on your device for the first time, does it prompt you to allow the relevant permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Does your app manifest declare permissions for bluetooth to be used?

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#Permissions

> In order to use Bluetooth features in your application, you must declare two permissions. The first of these is BLUETOOTH. You need this permission to perform any Bluetooth communication, such as requesting a connection, accepting a connection, and transferring data.
>
> The other permission that you must declare is either
>   ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. A location permission
>   is required because Bluetooth scans can be used to gather information
>   about the location of the user. This information may come from the
>   user's own devices, as well as Bluetooth beacons in use at locations
>   such as shops and transit facilities.

Comment: Yes it does, you can download the code from github and check it you want please

Comment: Hey, I'm probably looking at the wrong file (please tell me if I am) however I don't see the permission for Course_Location or Fine_Location listed in your manifest here https://github.com/rishadali/bluetooth-thermal-printer/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml 

If I'm making a mistake please let me know and I'd love to help further :)

Comment: Hi James, Yes I have added the location permissions as well but it is still not working... Can you try to download the project and generate release apk yourself, please, to see if you can spot something?? Thank you

Comment: Hey, yeah I'll give it a go myself tonight if it's still unsolved -J

Comment: Hi, did you have a chance to try this?

Comment: Hey, I'm not too sure if I will be able to get Android Studio running locally on my home pc, if you have any debug logs or anything that could be helpful please post it here and I'll try my best to help.

Comment: It looks like there is some issue with the WorkService class, if I remove the WorkService, it starts fine in release mode

Comment: I have also started bounty on this question for 50 point, if you could have a chance to look into it please.

Comment: Thanks for the info, especially with the workclass, definitely helps to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

If it only happens when u sign the apk, it looks like u have to update ur proguard rules, to exclude the printer lib clases or similar

Comment: I have tried to update and even disable proguard rules but it did not help. If you can download the project from github and try to fix it, that will be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for the application not responding is that you stop the main thread for 3 seconds on line 60 in the click listener of the button.
Replace the *onCreate()* method with the code below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Get the activity
    this.activity = this;

    //Button from the XML view
    btnConnect = findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);

    //Start the Init Work Service Async task
    new InitWorkService().execute();

    final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    //Set onClickListener for test print button
    btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
            es.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    connect();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

private void connect() {
    try {
        //Check if name and address are set
        if (name != null && mac_address != null && mac_address.contains(":")) {

            if (!WorkService.workThread.isConnected()) {
                WorkService.workThread.connectBt(mac_address);
                //Sleep for 3 seconds
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            //Check if connected
            if (WorkService.workThread.isConnected()) {
                //Collect data in background Thread
                new PrintData().execute();
            } else {
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, Global.toast_notconnect, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Please setup printer first!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e.fillInStackTrace());
    }
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            btnConnect.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Now the connection part executes in a new thread and only the UI operations go on the main one.

**Please note** that this code is not the optimal solution because it does not take into account the activity lifecycle. If the activity is re-created while the thread sleeps, there is still a reference kept to the old activity. But it should be a starting point for you.

Comment: I have tried this but it did not work. If you can download the project from github and try to fix it, that would be great

Comment: I did download the project and ran it. The _Thread.sleep(3000)_ was causing problems when clicking on the button. When I replaced it with the code above, the app was responsive.
Maybe you could describe in more detail the issue you are facing.
I also generated a signed release build which was behaving exactly as the debug one.

Comment: Thank you for the update, for me `Thread.sleep(3000)` is not the issue. `setOnClickListener` is only called when you press the button. Even if I remove the clickListener (or the button completely) it still have issues. It looks like there is some issue with the WorkService class, if I remove the `new InitWorkService().execute();` , it starts fine in release mode.